# Empty dataframe returned from xml data using xmlToDataframe in R

Tags: r, xml, httr

Working with an xml data that was downloaded using GET function from the httr package. The content returned is of type application/xml. An extract is as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata xmlns="http://example.com/schema/dxf/2.0">
  <pager>
    <page>1</page>
    <pageCount>17</pageCount>
    <total>819</total>
    <pageSize>50</pageSize>
    <nextPage>https://xxx.org.ng/xxx/api/indicators?page=2&amp;format=xml</nextPage>
  </pager>
  <indicators>
    <indicator id="cfvVUWwkwje">
      <displayName> ART Total </displayName>
    </indicator>
    <indicator id="gytvOB3J7">
      <displayName> ART Microscopy - Total</displayName>
    </indicator>
    <indicator id="5fgtZdtvQRW">
      <displayName> ART Microscopy Biology - Total</displayName>
    </indicator>
    <indicator id="g6hYenEHnsu">
      <displayName> ART GeneXpert - Total </displayName>
    </indicator>
    <indicator id="hhjxxDlG87j">
      <displayName> ART Functional -Total</displayName>
    </indicator>
    <indicator id="SarCtUBpBru">
      <displayName> ART 21 - Total</displayName>
    </indicator>
    <indicator id="ftywhPKoMgp">
      <displayName> Buruli Ulcer Total</displayName>
    </indicator>
    <indicator id="gyyhtAzCQZ0">
      <displayName> xART 21 prophylaxis Functional -Total</displayName>
    </indicator>
    <indicator id="vftWafaROyq0">
      <displayName> xART 21 Non Functional - Total</displayName>
    </indicator>
    </indicators>
</metadata>
```

I used the following code to download and tried to convert the xml to dataframe as shown below:

```
url_xml <- modify_url(url1, path = path)
xml_response <- GET(url_xml, authenticate(username, password))

http_type(xml_response)
resp_content <- content(xml_response)

parsed_content <- xmlParse(resp_content)

# get the root
parsed_xml_root <- xmlRoot(parsed_content)
# parse out names and IDs
df_xml <- xmlToDataFrame(nodes = getNodeSet(parsed_xml_root,"//indicators/indicator/displayName"))
id <- xmlSApply(parsed_xml_root[["indicator"]], xmlGetAttr, "id")
all_values_df <- cbind(df_xml, id)
```

I want to get the id of the indicator and the display name. The resulting dataframe was empty. Please any suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it solved

```
df_xml <- xmlToDataFrame(nodes = xmlChildren(xmlRoot(parsed_content)[["indicators"]]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your xml file has a namespace associated with it.  So first you need to retrieve the namespace and then add it to the parsing expressions.

```
library(XML)

#get namespace
nsDefs <- xmlNamespaceDefinitions(parsed_content, simplify = FALSE)
ns <- structure(sapply(nsDefs, function(x) x$uri), names = names(nsDefs))

#rename namespace and add it the node queries
df_xml <- xmlToDataFrame(getNodeSet(parsed_content, "/x:metadata//x:indicators//x:indicator//x:displayName", c(x=ns)))

#find indicator nodes then get attribute
nodes <-getNodeSet(parsed_content, "/x:metadata//x:indicators//x:indicator", c(x=ns))
id <- xmlSApply(nodes, xmlGetAttr, "id")

#put it all together
all_values_df <- cbind(df_xml, id)
```